# How add date of archive in the name of the archive with Export data options command in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a problem. I want to create a file with the function Export Data Options and I want the date of the archive in the name of the file. I am trying to create a variable test in order to do it, but it doesn't function. Do you have any idea how can I solve it ?

```
 SELECT
CONCAT("'gs://archivage-base/base1_",today,"*.csv'") as test
FROM
  (SELECT
CURRENT_DATE()  as today);

EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri=test,
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=true,
  field_delimiter=';') AS
SELECT * FROM `base-042021.campagnemakers.makerlocal`
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL functions right within your uri declaration as such. Examples: current_date(), current_datetime(), etc. Check out [this article](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#datetime_functions) for dozens of options.

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
    uri='gs://bucket_name/my_prefix/my_archive_name_'||current_date()||'-part-*.csv',
    format='CSV',
    overwrite=true,
    header=true,
    field_delimiter=';') AS
    SELECT * FROM `base-042021.campagnemakers.makerlocal`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a description to your code and how it answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate).

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE """
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://bucket_name/my_prefix/my_archive_name_@EXPORT_DATE-part-*.csv',
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=true,
  field_delimiter=';') AS
SELECT * FROM `base-042021.campagnemakers.makerlocal`
"""
using current_date('+/- time offset from UTC') as EXPORT_DATE
```

Also note that you have to specify an URI with a wildcard because the result of the query to export might be very large see [EXPORT DATA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_option_list) docs.

For more information on how to specify a [timezone](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timezone_definitions)

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is a scripting capability that allows to create SQL statement from a string at runtime so you can modify any part fo the SQL statement. You could even create a stored procedure that will get a table name as input and a GCS prefix to be able to export different tables to different location via a simple call to a stored procedure.

Comment: Hello, When I use this command, the archive name is: my_archive_name_@EXPORT_DATE-part-*.csv . There is not the current date as date.

Comment: @Stephane, can you please provide more information? I tested and it work as expected. Thew only reason I can think that could explain why the date is different is the use of timezone. `current_date()` default to UTC timezone. I updated the code to specify your offset

Comment: I used the command, and i choose my timezone, but here is the name of the file:  makerlocal_@EXPORT_DATE-part-000000000000.csv

Comment: @Stephane is correct. This sample does not work. Eric Qiu's answer below however does work. I recommend following his code suggestion replacing the EXPORT_DATE and using clause in this answer with a simple ||current_date()|| call right in the uri.

Though Eric didn't give a lot of detail with his answer, it is the solution and I'm sure he'd appreciate it if you marked it as such.